# Aligning multiple objects along a shaped line

Tags: bezier-curves

Building a human skeleton, trying to learn new skills apart from sculpting, so for the spine I wonder what the best way would be to align the vertebrae along a spine-shaped line.
I drew the line as BezierCurve:
[image]

I'm pretty sure there is one or another way to do it automatically, instead of just aligning each piece manually. Any clues are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: yes, if your vertebres are one unique object (if not you can join them with ctrl J) you can use a Curve modifier and they will follow your curve (make sure to put both their origin at the same position)

Comment: Superb, thanks a lot!